# how to execute Unix Shell Commands with Python in windows

Tags: python, windows

I want to use `os.system()` [in Python] to run UNIX shell commands in Windows environment, **Pycharm**.

for eaxmple:

```
os.system("ls")
os.system("cat file.txt")
```

Is there any way to do this? thank you!

Comment: `run UNIX shell commands in Windows environment` How can it work if your windows operating system doesn't have `ls` command? You have python installed doesn't mean you've all *nix commands available.

Comment: You'll have to install WSL to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: You need to install WSL and install Python **under WSL**: https://medium.com/@rhdzmota/python-development-on-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-17a0fa1839d